# How to create an alarm that goes during a countdown timer created with an AnimationController?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, countdown, flutter-animation

I have created a countdown timer using an animation controller with the following method(posted below). I'm aware of executing code when the timer is complete, but I'm wondering if there is a way to execute a function after a certain amount of time while the countdown timer is still running. In this case, I want to set off an alarm sound 10 seconds before the timer is complete to let the user know that their time is almost up. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Timer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TimerState();
  }
}

class _TimerState extends State<Timer> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  int _timerDuration = 2;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(minutes: _timerDuration));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Countdown(
            animation: StepTween(
              begin: _timerDuration * 60,
              end: 0,
            ).animate(_controller),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


class Countdown extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countdown({Key key, this.animation}) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    Duration clockTimer = Duration(seconds: animation.value);

    String timerText =
        '${clockTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString()}:${(clockTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60) % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';

    return Text(
      "$timerText",
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timer and set the callback to play the sound:

```
Timer(Duration(<Your duration minus 10 sec>), () {
      // play the sound here
    });
```

To play a sound, take a look at this post: https://fluttercentral.com/Articles/Post/1234/How_to_play_an_audio_file_in_flutter

Comment: I tried the method you posted, and the timer and callback do not play on the designated time that is reflected on the Animated Countdown. In this case, it should play when 10 seconds appear on the clock but the Timer itself didn't work until the 8 second mark.

Comment: You problems seems to be the synchrony. The problem is that the AnimatedWidget is not exactly synchronized with the time and frame rate. You will need a way to track the time within the frame rates (inside the build method). I suggest you to track the initial timestamp (DateTime.now()) and to call a function inside of the build method which will calculate the passed time and to start to play the sound when the time exceeds the desired duration. I can post an exemple when I leave work.

Comment: Don't forget to load the sound before, it can lead to delays if done at the moment the sound should be starting to play.

Comment: Thank you, that would be incredibly appreciated. Looking forward to the example.